# Mezzanine StackedDynamicInlineAdmin delete row

Tags: jquery, django, mezzanine

I'm using Django with Mezzanine and I would like to have a variable number of pictures for a given "Plugin" instance. Do do so, I've used a "PluginScreenshot" model with a ForeignKey pointing to the associated "Plugin" and an ImageField to store the pictures.

It works correctly but in order to make it editable by the admin, I've tried to use the StackedDynamicInlineAdmin object of Mezzanine, and even if the "Add another" and "Delete Item" links are present, I can only add a new row. If I click on "Delete Item", nothing changes (I don't have a red row that will disappear while hitting on the save button). There is no error message in the console view of FireBug.

Here is a screenshot of the situation : I would like to remove row 2 and row 3.
[image: Impossible to delete rows]

Any Ideas? I can reproduce the "bug" on Firefox 30.0 and on Chrome 35.0. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using : http://mezzanine.jupo.org/fr/admin/shop/product/10/ (demo/demo) and the source code of Cartridge https://github.com/stephenmcd/cartridge.

I needed this JS to have it working : http://mezzanine.jupo.org/static/grappelli/js/admin/Inline.js